# Most of my Raspberry Pi wlan0 stopped connecting despite otherwise-identical configurations and eth0 fine

Tags: networking

tI run a Unifi Dream Router (UDR) and two U6 satellites (wired backhaul to the UDR). I do not block any MACs/IPs (at present).

Recently, all but two of my RPis (5 of 7 Pi 4B+ 4GB, 2 Pi 4B+ 8GB, 1 Pi 3B+) have stopped connecting to Wifi, within a day of each other.

All except one of the two RPis with working wifi are standard downloaded images from raspberrypi.org; the non-standard Pi with working wifi is NEMS (but not configured beyond the basics).

No detected issues with their Ethernet connections (I can connect into them all on their eth0 IPs, and access each Pi's specific resources - nagios, NAS, OpenHAB, Home Assistant, etc.).

No detected issues with any other device on my network on Ethernet or Wifi (and I have ~300 total, mostly Wifi mostly IoT devices like plugs, switches, sensors; so netmask is 23/512).

Every device on the network has a Fixed IP - all specified in DHCP and some devices (like the Pis) configured with the IPs. (Each RPi eth0 and wlan0 MAC has its own IP, of course; they're always within one of each other, as in 192.168.86.33 and 192.168.86.34.)

I used to run Pihole on two of the Pis (including one of the two where Wifi is still working), but turned it off to try to diagnose this Wifi issue. (I had the Pihole setup configured identically, all MACs registered to a fixed IP and running DHCP.)

All have all the latest updates from release (not experimental) paths. (I update nightly.)

I BELIEVE at this point it's something about a recent UDR update, but I can't PROVE it to Ubiquiti so they won't investigate. I'd appreciate your help in further diagnosing. I don't know some of the "under-the-hood" diagnostics for this, and my searches have pointed to nothing applicable to Raspberry's configs.

What I see in my VNC sessions is the Wifi going up for 2-3 seconds and then down for 2-3 seconds infinitely.

Here's some of my diagnostics.

ifconfig

Always shows my eth0 and lo, and if I catch the timing right (i.e., the second it's up) it'll show wlan0, or I can specify...

ifconfig wlan0

It always returns:

```
wlan0: flags=-28670<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC>  mtu 1500
        ether (hidden here)  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 121  bytes 6156 (6.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 972 (972.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If I catch it temporarily connected, that command will show additional flag of "up" (thus different value for "flags=") but nothing else changes. (That list of values is on a box running for over four days, so obviously 131 total packets in 4 days means it's not connecting.)

I've tried several variations for /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf, both with and without "key_mgmt", and with one or both of my Wifi networks. I've tried configuring by hand as well as from raspi-config. Example:

```
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="(mywifinet)"
    psk="(mypw)"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}

network={
    ssid="(myguestwifi)-Guest"
    psk="(myguestpw)"
}
```

Folder is u: root, g: root, perms 755 on all wpa_supplicant file is u: root, g: root, perms 600 on all

I've tried both "systemctl restart wpa_supplicant", and rebooting after changes, just in case the (in)famous "duplicate process" issue is the problem in restarting the service. "systemctl status..."

I've also tried configuring through the VNC applet (which shows wlan0 appearing and disappearing), and even trying to "time it right" by entering the password (during the time the wifi icon disappears) and only hitting [Enter] when the wifi icon reappears.

It's not "rfkill"; all the devices (working and nonworking) show the same:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0     blocked unblocked
```

Each box's "/etc/dhcpcd.conf" (user: root, group: netdev, perms 664 on all boxes) is the following (with specific hostname per box and specific IPs per interface per box) (only the uncommented and non-blank rows):

```
hostname (boxname)
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
option ntp_servers
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.86.(ethip)/23
static routers=192.168.86.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.86.1

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.86.(wifiip)/23
static routers=192.168.86.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.86.1
```

I have over 300 devices, so my netmask is 23-bit instead of 24-bit

Not that it should matter, but my /etc/dhcp folder and contents are unchanged from install

Tried dozens of variations of a script of:

```
ip link set down wlan0
wpa_cli -i "wlan0" set country "US"
wpa_cli -i "wlan0" save_config 
raspi-config nonint do_wifi_country US
connmanctl enable wifi
rfkill unblock wifi
systemctl restart wpa_supplicant
sleep (various, from 2s to 30s)
ip link set up wlan0
```

I have tried variations of the order (obviously, up always after down), variations of which commands are commented, and so on. I suspected rkfill at one point. Sometimes, reboot causes rfkill to be lost, but not consistently.

All /etc/debian_version = 11.7 except one of the two 8GB Pi 4s.

All (per /etc/os-release) are bullseye except one of the two 8GB RPi 4 on Buster, all /etc/debian-version = 11.7 except the same Pi. Some of them are running 32-bit, some as 64-bit, no pattern there.

Some might suggest "copy configs from the working two to the others" - but all of them already run the same configs for /etc/dhcpcd.conf except for the IP-specific and hostname-specific info, and identical for /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. None of the hostnames are anything but 3-8 alphanumeric chars.

Edited to insert:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan|grep ESSID
```

Shows lots on the two that work. On the ones that don't work:

```
wlan0 Failed to read scan data : Network is down
```

So, my question to all of you is, what other diagnostic steps can I take to figure out why all but two of them do not connect on wireless, what commands can I run and logs can I capture?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `(I update nightly.)` have you considered the possibility of an update to the pi being responsible? Are raspberry pi's the only device having wifi issues? as for `no pattern there.` can you list out the devices with OS version, architecture (i.e. 32/64 bit) and if it's working or broken - perhaps a fresh pair of eyes will spot a pattern you can't

Comment: what happens if you reboot the router?

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved]

There was a script (I prob wrote long ago) that was misreading the network states and was trying to reconfigure the network. It had some bugs. Script removed and everything works fine.
Thanks to responders.